# Share Link on Facebook without thumbnail

Tags: facebook, share

I want to share a link on Facebook, using Facebook share API. The Link has no Image and also, I don't want to use any Image for it. Is there any way I can share URL on Facebook without using tag `og:image`.

Also, I received following error message,

> Object at URL '**MY_URL**' of type 'website' is invalid because *a required property 'og:image:url' of type 'url' was not provided.*

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) reference, `og:image` is a required property

> To turn your web pages into graph objects, you need to add basic
>   metadata to your page. We've based the initial version of the protocol
>   on RDFa which means that you'll place additional  tags in the
>    of your web page. The four required properties for every page
>   are:
>
> og:title - The title of your object as it should appear within the
>   graph, e.g., "The Rock".
>
> og:type - The type of your object, e.g.,
>   "video.movie". Depending on the type you specify, other properties may
>   also be required.
>
> og:image - An image URL which should represent your
>   object within the graph.
>
> og:url - The canonical URL of your object
>   that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g.,
>   "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".